# How do I add mesh lines to a function using straight webgl (no THREE.js)?

Tags: webgl

I'm new to WebGL and would line to add mesh lines to my function.  I've tried the barycentric coordinate approach here:

http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/

and that's not helpful.  Also, the fwidth function described in the article is not defined when I try to compile my shader.

What is the easiest way to add mesh lines to a function surface in webgl?  I'm not using THREE.js but would rather code it without the library.

Thanks,
Dominic

Comment: As mentioned in the article, `fwidth` requires enabling [OES_standard_derivatives extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_standard_derivatives/) using `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable` in the beginning of the shader.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for replying.  I included that command in my fragment shader but I obtain the message from Chrome: GL_OES_standard_derivaties:  extension not supported.  I tried to run it in Explorer and Edge and get similar messages.  The article above is unclear under what conditions I can use the extension.  Can someone explain to me what browser and what version allows this extension to be used?

Comment: Also, when I execute var extensions = gl.getSupportedExtensions(); my browser includes OES_standard_derivative in the list of supported extensions yet when I attempt to use fwidth, the shader cannot be compiled because of the unknown "fwidth" function.

Comment: The extension is available on pretty much every platform(99%), you can see [availability of extensions on webglstats.com](http://webglstats.com/). To use it you need to enable the extension by calling `getExtension("OES_standard_derivatives")` **and** having the aforementioned preprocessor statement in your shader code.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks a lot.  The shader is now compiling with that addition.  However, it's not clear at all in the article how to set up the barycentric points for each vertex.  When I try to set them up with just a cube for example some of the faces are meshed, but other faces have either one or both triangles shaded-out completely.  I have tried to find resources on the net and those are unclear as well.  Do you know of a good reference which explains how to set up these points?

Comment: If I can add one more thing:  I'm working with algebraic functions.  However, might someone explain to me how to set up the barycentric points for example, the simple function sin(xy)?

Comment: what does sin(xy) have to do with barycentric coordinates!?!?!?

Comment: Hi guys.  I did get barycentric and fwidth to seemingly work but the anti-alias is not acceptable or I'm not doing it correctly.  The sin(xy) comment was just to use it as a simple example.  I do like the low-level code, shaders and WegGL, but I am also starting to look at both THREE.js and mathbox.

Comment: Ok I got it:  I misunderstood the labeling of the triangle vertices:  When we pass three vertices of the triangle to drawElements, the first vertex is labeled (1,0,0),  the second is (0,1,0), and the third is (0,0,1).  Next triangle gets the same labels and so on.  Works nice now.

Comment: Here's my fragment shader for the record:

Answer (score 0):

For purpose of that article, barycentric coord is just assigning (1,0,0) to the first vertex of triangle, (0,1,0) to the second, and (0,0,1) to the third.

Then to draw the wireframe, its basically just this:

```
if(any(lessThan(attr_bcoords, vec3(0.012)))){
    color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // black
}
```

The `fwidth` version is nicer because it draws anti aliased line.